# How to use libjpeg complex macros with Swift?

Tags: swift, c-preprocessor, libjpeg

When I try to call libjpeg’s `jpeg_create_decompress()` function, I get

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/jconfig.h:8:34: error: invalid suffix '.0' on floating constant
#define LIBJPEG_TURBO_VERSION 1.5.0
                             ^
.../main.swift:49:5: error: use of unresolved identifier 'jpeg_create_decompress'
jpeg_create_decompress(&info)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CJPEG.jpeg_CreateDecompress:1:13: note: did you mean 'jpeg_CreateDecompress'?
public func jpeg_CreateDecompress(_ cinfo: j_decompress_ptr!, _ version: Int32, _ structsize: Int)
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
```

Now, looking inside `jpeglib.h` I see

```
/* Initialization of JPEG compression objects.
 * jpeg_create_compress() and jpeg_create_decompress() are the exported
 * names that applications should call.  These expand to calls on
 * jpeg_CreateCompress and jpeg_CreateDecompress with additional information
 * passed for version mismatch checking.
 * NB: you must set up the error-manager BEFORE calling jpeg_create_xxx.
 */
#define jpeg_create_compress(cinfo) \
    jpeg_CreateCompress((cinfo), JPEG_LIB_VERSION, \
                        (size_t) sizeof(struct jpeg_compress_struct))
#define jpeg_create_decompress(cinfo) \
    jpeg_CreateDecompress((cinfo), JPEG_LIB_VERSION, \
                          (size_t) sizeof(struct jpeg_decompress_struct))
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateCompress (j_compress_ptr cinfo, int version,
                                  size_t structsize);
EXTERN(void) jpeg_CreateDecompress (j_decompress_ptr cinfo, int version,
                                    size_t structsize);
```

The `jpeg_create_decompress` isn’t available, probably as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31):

> Complex macros are used in C and Objective-C but have no counterpart in Swift. Complex macros are macros that do not define constants, including parenthesized, function-like macros. You use complex macros in C and Objective-C to avoid type-checking constraints or to avoid retyping large amounts of boilerplate code. However, macros can make debugging and refactoring difficult. In Swift, you can use functions and generics to achieve the same results without any compromises. *Therefore, the complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source files are not made available to your Swift code*.

But without this macro, how do I use `libjpeg` with Swift?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way around redefining them in Swift, for example:

```
class JPEGLibWrapper {

    class func jpeg_create_decompress(cinfo: j_decompress_ptr) {
        jpeg_CreateDecompress(cinfo, JPEG_LIB_VERSION, MemoryLayout<jpeg_decompress_struct>.size)
    }
}
```

Or in Objective-C:

```m
@interface JPEGLibWrapper : NSObject

+ (void) jpeg_create_decompress:(j_decompress_ptr)cinfo;

@end

@implementation JPEGLibWrapper

+ (void) jpeg_create_decompress:(j_decompress_ptr)cinfo {
    jpeg_create_decompress(cinfo);
}

@end
```

(Better naming could be used...)

**EDIT** I just noticed you're using Swift on Linux, correct? I don't know how the Swift–C bridging is done on Linux but I guess could do something similar to the Objective-C code but in a C file.

The advantage of declaring an Objective-C or C method/function over doing it in Swift is that in the former you're actually using the complex macro, therefore avoiding (mis)translating it. You just declare a wrapper method/function around it and expose it to Swift.

Source:

- https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/29/converting-complex-objective-c-macros-swift-functions/
- https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/from-objective-c-to-swift-use-complex-define-macros-in-swift-28cdff464fc7